# Typescript, Prevent Bootstrap Dropdown from closing when button is clicked

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, typescript, dropdown

I make a simple bootstrap dropdown to do a registration or login. Inside the dropdown we have text and button like "dont have account? `register`", "already have account? 
 `login`". The `register` and `login` are buttons for changing form. But when the button clicked the dropdown is closed and we have to click to open the dropdown again to see/use the other form. I wanted to prevent this bootstrap dropdown from closing when these buttons inside it are clicked. The dropdown is inside `app.component` and the form is inside `app.parent`. I'm using angular cli typescript.

```js
//component.ts
changeForm() {
  this.isNewUser = !this.isNewUser
}
```

```html
<!--app.component.html-->
<div>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" auto-close="disabled">REGISTER/LOGIN <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <app-parent></app-parent>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<!--parent.component.html-->
<div *ngIf="isNewUser">
  <p *ngIf="errorMessage.length > 0" class="text-danger">{{errorMessage}}</p>
  <p *ngIf="error.message.length > 0" class="text-danger">{{error.message}}</p>
  <form (ngSubmit)="onSignUp()">...</form>
  <h4 class="text-primary">Already have an Account? <button type="submit" href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" (click)="changeForm()">Log In</button></h4>
</div>

<div *ngIf="!isNewUser">
  <p *ngIf="errorMessage.length > 0" class="text-danger">{{errorMessage}}</p>
  <p *ngIf="error.message.length > 0" class="text-danger">{{error.message}}</p>
  <form (ngSubmit)="onLoginEmail()">...</form>
  <h4 class="text-primary">Not have any Account yet? <button type="submit" href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" (click)="changeForm()">Register</button></h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the answer by using `event.stopPropagation();​` function and put it inside my `changeForm()` function.

```js
changeForm() {
  this.isNewUser = !this.isNewUser;
  event.stopPropagation();​
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have included jquery in your app project then write in your component file **var $ as any;** then in your changeForm function you can write $("#dropdown").addClass('open'); where you have to give id attribute to your as  **dropdown**.